Azure App Services built in auth programatic log out
I am working on an azure app services application using built in auth. I am trying to implement an auto logout due to inactivity feature, so when the user steps away from their browser the app should log out.
Following the documentation of how to sign out of a session I would expect when I redirect to /.auth/logout it should

Clears authentication cookies from the current session.
Deletes the current user's tokens from the token store.
For Microsoft Entra and Google, performs a server-side sign-out on the identity provider.

... however, instead of doing the above, the user is presented with an account chooser screen to ask which account to sign out of. The problem is that there is no user there to make the choice, so the browser hangs on that screen, and when visiting the application the user is still authenticated.
Does anyone know how to programatically log out of azure app services apps without requiring user interaction?

please share the code that you've tried.

@Sirra Sneha - Lol.... What code do u expect to be shared in this case?

My bad I didn't see built-in auth.

@Billy Moon Have you implemented any JavaScript to track user activity or inactivity?

@SirraSneha I have, but the issue is more generally how to programatically log out. The error is not in the inactivity code, but rather the method of logging out. Even if I do window.location to the auth logout from the console it does not log the user out.

This is for oidc, but there's an optional parameter called logout_hint that bypasses the user selection. Maybe, this can help: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/entra/identity-platform/v2-protocols-oidc#send-a-sign-out-request

Yep logout_hint should work => /.auth/logout?logout_hint=<user-email-to-logout>

To make sure user is logged out, you should force clear the auth cookies.
E.g.
// your api endpoint to log out

res.clearCookie('AppServiceAuthSession'); // Example cookie
res.redirect('/.auth/logout?post_logout_redirect_uri=/logged-out');


1. Introduction
Your browser triggers requests to your server. Your task is to replicate those requests programmatically.
2. The plan
You are at whatever page and you intend to run a JS code when either the browser or the tab loses focus. You can use window.onblur for that purpose.
3. Research
Do an actual logout as a user with Dev Tools being open and monitor all requests, save the curl of each one. Notice that some requests may reuse some responses of previous requests.
For each such request, determine:

whether it's necessary for the logout (for example you don't want to send requests to CSS files)
what parameters/headers of the request vary (session ID, user agent, whatever) and particularly what variable values depend on responses from the earlier requests
what headers are to be sent

4. Implementation
Implement a sequence of these requests and adjust them until they work. Carefully monitor what the responses are. Try doing it in curl and during your tests inspire from a living browser session.
5. Integrating it into your project
Now that you have a sequence of curl requests that take some parameters and via the sequential sending of the requests you are able to log out, you might be able to send these requests via Javascript if you stumble into no browser limitations. In such a case, you will just need to implement some Javascript functions and trigger the sequence at window.onblur.
However, if there are limitations in the browser and you cannot solve it, then implement a middleware to which you pass the initial variable values and which starts the sequence of requests and trigger this from your Javascript code by requesting to your middleware.

Use JavaScript to monitor user activity. If user is inactive for a defined period, trigger the logout process:
let timeout;
const logoutAfterInactivity = 10 * 60 * 1000; // 10 minutes

const resetTimer = () => {
    clearTimeout(timeout);
    timeout = setTimeout(() => {
        window.location.href = '/.auth/logout?post_logout_redirect_uri=/';
    }, logoutAfterInactivity);
};

// Listen for user activity
['mousemove', 'keypress', 'click', 'scroll'].forEach(event => {
    window.addEventListener(event, resetTimer, false);
});

resetTimer(); // Initialize the timer

Include post_logout_redirect_uri parameter in your logout URL to dodge the account chooser and redirect to wherever you want:
window.location.href = '/.auth/logout?post_logout_redirect_uri=https://your-page-url';

To make things a bit more smooth you can load the logout URL in a hidden iframe so the user isn’t redirected away:
const iframe = document.createElement('iframe');
iframe.style.display = 'none';
iframe.src = '/.auth/logout?post_logout_redirect_uri=https://your-page-url';
document.body.appendChild(iframe);

Invalidate tokens on the backend. In a database, set their status to inactive or delete them.
Bonus Points: Use a Proxy Endpoint If  /.auth/logout endpoint doesn't behave as expected, create your own logout endpoint on the backend. This endpoint can clear local session data, redirect the user to the identity provider's logout URL with the correct parameters, redirect the user back to your app etc...
Ensure HTTPS context and SameSite cookie policies are appropriately configured.
In addition to the inactivity timer, you might want to adjust token expiration.
